# Mongo query slow, data shows before query

Tags: mongodb, meteor, delay

I have created two templates ( **A** and **B**).

**A** - Shows up when a user **has not** created documents in a certain Mongo collection.

**B** - Shows up if the user **has** created documents in the collection.

Essentially I am displaying a "Theres nothing here message" when no content exists.

To achieve this I use a helper to query mongo to check if documents exist. It looks like the following:

```
defaultCheck: function() {
  var offerid = this.offerAccepted;

  var id = Meteor.userId();

  var result = Listing.find({
    $or: [{
      creator_id: Meteor.userId(),
      status: "Completed"
    }, {
      offer_creator: Meteor.userId(),
      status: "Completed"
    }]
  });

  return Boolean(result.count());
}
```

So this returns a true or false Boolean value.

In my layout template I use #if to check the value of the `defaultCheck` helper and either hide or show the **A** or **B** Template

```
{{#if defaultCheck}}
{{#each meetup}}
{{> ProfileActiveCard}}
{{/each}}
{{else}}
{{> DefaultProfileActive}}
{{/if}}
```

The Issue is that the query is too slow and the **A** template briefly shows up (flickers) before the query completes.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Instead of immediately showing the Not Found template, you could have a [`spinner`](https://github.com/SachaG/meteor-spin) to show that data is loading. After query is completed, check if result length is 0 or greater. If 0 show Not Found, else display the data.

Comment: I don't know how to check for when the query is completed. If that confusion was cleared up, your suggestion would work.

Comment: I posted an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggested way to show a spinner while data loads:

**Private variables:**

```
var isDataLoaded = false;
```

**Helpers:**

```
dataLoaded: function() {
  return isDataLoaded;
}

defaultCheck: function() {
  var offerid = this.offerAccepted;

  var id = Meteor.userId();

  var result = Listing.find({
    $or: [{
      creator_id: Meteor.userId(),
      status: "Completed"
    }, {
      offer_creator: Meteor.userId(),
      status: "Completed"
    }];
  });

  isDataLoaded = true; // should be set to true only after database query finishes

  return Boolean(result.count());
}
```

**Template:**

```
{{#if !dataLoaded}}
    {{> spinner}}
{{else}}
    {{#if defaultCheck}}
        {{#each meetup}}
            {{> ProfileActiveCard}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        {{> NoDataFoundTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

I am not 100% sure this will work as expected or if it's the best way to do it, but it's a start.